# Config vars with multiple values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

In my Rails application I have a feature that I only want to open to users that are logged in with a certain e-mail (We use Devise for user authentication). I have a method to check if a user is `current_user.is_privileged?`

```
def is_privileged?
 Settings.privileged_users.include?(email)
end
```

In `config/settings/test.yml` I set the privileged users as:

```
privileged_users: ['chesa@example.com', 'random@example.com']
```

In production on the other hand I was thinking about using config variable like:

```
#config/settings.yml
privileged_users: ENV["PRIVILEGED_USERS"]
```

My question is if I can set multiple values to that variable in an array? I'm deploying my app to Heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original question was if an env variable could be an array. The answer is no, not an Heroku anyway, as https://github.com/railsconfig/rails_config states concerning arrays in section heroku: 
"It won't work with arrays, though.". We [ended up](https://github.com/AgileVentures/WebsiteOne/pull/588) with storing multiple values as a string and splitting them. Thx [Rene](https://github.com/erpe)!

`ENV['PRIVILEGED_USERS'] = "one@example.com, two@example.com"`

```
def is_privileged?
 Settings.privileged_users.split(',').include?(email)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass in an array as a string and YAML should parse it correctly.

So your settings will remain the same and your env variable will be:

```
PRIVILEGED_USERS="['chesa@example.com', 'random@example.com']"
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, settings files should really be used for truly static or configuration data.  Are you sure you don't want to have a `privileged` flag on your User model and just store this info in the database?  Then you wouldn't have to redeploy the code just to change who is on that list:

```
class AddPrivilegedFlagToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up ; add_column :users, :privileged, :boolean, :default => false ; end
  def down ; remove_column :users, :privileged
end
```

and then your check is simply:

```
if current_user.privileged?  
  # do stuff
end
```

Comment: You are right @armando. This is a better long term solution and we will probably incorporate that later down the road.